# Cypher APOC - Aggregations should not be used like this

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.uid IN $uids
WITH n as nodes, apoc.agg.minItems(n, n.level).items as highestNode
MATCH (nodes)-[:TRANSLATES_TO]-(a) where a.tree_id = apoc.agg.first(highestNode).tree_id
return nodes, a
```

I'm getting the error `Aggregations should not be used like this.` This is happening when introducing the `first` function on the third line of the query. `minItems` returns a map with the same key for each node so I need to get the first element of the map somehow. What `minItems` returns:

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just need to get the first node returned from the `minItems` function. It seems my use of the `first()` function is throwing the error, maybe it can't be used in a MATCH statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `min()` function and then used the value of that in a list comprehension like this:

```
match (n) where n.uid in $uids
with collect(n) as nodes, min(n.level) as min
with nodes, [x in nodes where x.level = min][0] as minNode
unwind nodes as node
match (node)-[:TRANSLATES_TO]-(a) where a.tree_id = minNode.tree_id
return node, a
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `apoc.agg.first`, since `highestNode` is a list. You can use indices, like this:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.uid IN $uids
WITH n as nodes, apoc.agg.minItems(n, n.level).items as highestNode
MATCH (nodes)-[:TRANSLATES_TO]-(a) where a.tree_id = highestNode[0]
return nodes, a
```

Comment: `minItems` returns a map, not a list

Comment: You are fetching just items from the map `apoc.agg.minItems(n, n.level).items` @JonFlynn

Comment: I was wrong in my description. `minItems` returns a map for each node processed. I've added a screenshot of what it returns in the description

Comment: Ok, so do just want to use the first map only?

Comment: yep, and then use the `tree_id` property in the next MATCH statement

Comment: Try this:

```MATCH (n) WHERE n.uid IN $uids
WITH n as nodes, apoc.agg.minItems(n, n.level).items as highestNode
WITH nodes, apoc.agg.first(highestNode).tree_id AS highestTreeId
MATCH (nodes)-[:TRANSLATES_TO]-(a) WHERE a.tree_id = highestTreeId
return nodes, a```

Comment: Or this:

```MATCH (n) WHERE n.uid IN $uids
WITH n as nodes, apoc.agg.minItems(n, n.level).items as highestNode
UNWIND highestNode AS hn
WITH nodes, apoc.agg.first(hn).tree_id AS highestTreeId
MATCH (nodes)-[:TRANSLATES_TO]-(a) WHERE a.tree_id = highestTreeId
return nodes, a```

Comment: But I still don't get your use-case. I believe we are using the `first` function in an incorrect way.

Comment: Yep, `first` is now not throwing an error for me but it's not having any effect on getting the first map. Using unwind works for getting the first map but then reduces the number of rows being returned to one.

Comment: there should be an option to return the full node after any aggregation function, this could have been solved easily using the `min` function if that functionality existed. I've also posted this question in the community: https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/return-full-node-after-aggregation-function/m-p/62285#M36805